# HTACCES : Change url more friendly

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to make the url of my web more friendly and easy to find by google.

This is my url of my web :
www.myweb.com/news.php?id=12&title=title-of-my-news

I want to change to be :
www.myweb.com/news/12/title-of-my-news

Anyone can help me, the sysntax on htacces?

Answer (score 0):

Add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+news\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&title=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /news/%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /news.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

You'll also need to make sure all of the links on your pages are absolute URL's, or add this to your page header:

```
<base href="/" />
```